# Changing legend text size coefplot

Tags: legend, stata, coefplot

I am working on coefplot and I would like to readjust the legend size of the labels to vsmall. However, when I use labsize(vsmall)). I get an error. Am I missing a specific step within coefplot?

```
coefplot weight height, xtitle(Medical Records) ytitle(Share) ///
vertical recast(bar) barwidth(0.15) finten(60)  plotlabels("male" "female" "child"   ///
"adult", labsize(vsmall)) graphregion(color(white)) bgcolor(white)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will want to remove `labsize(vsmall)` from your command entirely, and add `legend(size(vsmall))` to the end of your command as an option. Your final command should look like this:

```
coefplot weight height, xtitle(Medical Records) ytitle(Share) vertical recast(bar) barwidth(0.15) finten(60) plotlabels("male" "female" "child" "adult") graphregion(color(white)) bgcolor(white) legend(size(vsmall))
```